# Our Honor is Unstained

Tags: cipher, visual, knowledge, geography

Here are four photos from Google satellite maps and one from Wikipedia (see note 1).  These photos show a family **related by strength and endurance**.  The goal of this puzzle is:

1. to identify the proper name of the each of the five family members
2. then to apply the book cipher method to identify the sixth member of this family

**Hints:**

- understanding the common characteristic is important
- there is no hidden information in the photos
- there are no legumes in the answers
- partial answers are OK

<sup>Note 1 - Photos of subject 3 are restricted by copyright so a photo of a model is shown below.</sup>

[image: First three]
[image: Second three]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper names are:

> 1. Gateway Arch (in St.Louis)
>
> 2. United States Air Force Memorial (in Arlington, VA)
>
> 3. Atomium (in Brussels)
>
> 4. Cloud Gate (in Chicago)
>
> 5. The Kelpies (at The Helix in Scotland)
>
> 6. Unisphere (in Flushing Meadows, NY) - credit to Len for this one!

The common characteristic of these is that they are:

> made out of stainless steel.

The book cipher is described as follows:

> It encodes the name of subject 6 by using the names of the first 5 subjects.  The first number X in parentheses represents the name of subject X, and the second number Y represents the Yth letter from the end of the name.
>
> So we have:
>
> * (4, -6) = the 6th letter from the end of "Cloud Gate" = U
> * N
> * (3, -3) = the 3rd letter from the end of "Atomium" = I
> * (5, -1) = the 1st letter from the end of "The Kelpies" = S
> * (5, -4) = the 4th letter from the end of "The Kelpies" = P
> * (1, -1) = the 1st letter from the end of "Gateway Arch" = H
> * (1, -8) = the 8th letter from the end of "Gateway Arch" = E
> * (2, -4) = the 4th letter from the end of "United States Air Force Memorial" = R
> * (2, -7) = the 7th letter from the end of "United States Air Force Memorial" = E
>
> That spells out Unisphere.

Comment: @Len I went down the wrong path trying to figure out the cipher.  I thought the title might have something to do with it, and I found the phrase "Our honor is unstained" in a couple books.  Also, I couldn't find The Kelpies in Google Maps, but I did find some photos showing they're supposed to be near water.  Your photo doesn't show any water, so that's why I wasn't sure about that one.

Comment: My apologies. I am learning there can be many different perspectives on how to solve a cipher and that they need to be very well defined.

Comment: @Len No need to apologize, there was nothing wrong with your puzzle. I just made it more difficult than it should have been!